# Drumming app - Laggy Sounds... How To Fix?

Tags: iphone, ios, audio

I have a drum app that I've created basing it off of `AVAudioPlayer` instead of the common system sounds in order to have a bit of control.

The problem is that whenever two or more sounds are played at once, it lags and stops alls sounds, so your drum beat gets choppy and randomly stopped.

For example: **boom boom chhhhh boom boom ch--- boom bo---- chhhhh**

If you can tell at all from that onomatopoeia.

Here's the sound code, I have an array of preloaded `AVAudioPlayer` so that it loads faster.

```
- (void)triggerSound:(NSInteger)soundNumber {
    NSInteger deltaNum = soundNumber*numberOfBuffers;
    AVAudioPlayer *lowBuffer = [bufferBox objectAtIndex:deltaNum];
    Boolean soundFired = FALSE;
    // Find an unused buffer if possible, otherwise play sound from first buffer.
    for (int i=0; i<numberOfBuffers; i++) {
        NSLog(@"Buffer loop: %d", i);
        NSLog(@"Buffer to load: %d", deltaNum);
        AVAudioPlayer *tempBuffer = [bufferBox objectAtIndex:deltaNum+i];
        if (!tempBuffer.playing) {
            tempBuffer.currentTime = 0;
            [tempBuffer play];
            soundFired = TRUE;
            break;
        } else if (lowBuffer.currentTime>tempBuffer.currentTime) {
            lowBuffer = tempBuffer;
        }
    }
    if (!soundFired) {
        lowBuffer.currentTime = 0;
        [lowBuffer play];
        soundFired = TRUE;
    }
}
```

That method is called in the IBAction button press. ex: [drumObject triggerSound:3].

All help appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had much better experiences with the `OpenAL` API for some games. It is very different and more low level (you have to deal with sources and buffers) but it worked much better for me than `AVAudioPlayer`.

Comment: *note* OpenAL does not support AAC or MP3 compression out of the box. You would have to manually decompress and stream those into your OpenAL buffers.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using an iOS game engine for your audio needs.

For example: http://gamua.com/sparrow/

You don't actually have to use the graphics part of this engine. Just import and use the audio part of the framework (which provides a simple API on top of OpenAL).

Comment: This is actually what I ended up doing a while back; I went with cocosdenshion as my engine, and it works great :)